# How to find object in JS where provided value match some property value criteria?

Tags: javascript

I have array of four JS object:

```
Object1 = {
    fee: 150
}

Object2 = {
    fee: 300
}

Object3 = {
    fee: 450
}

Object4 = {
    fee: 700
}
```

I need to find object where value that I provide via input is greater then fee of object but also less than fee of next one. There is also a case where value can not be less than fee of first one and if value is greater than fee of four one I need four one as result.

For example:

`value = 50`, `result = null`,

`value = 225`, `result = Object1`,

`value = 400`, `result = Object2`,

`value = 650`, `result = Object3`,

`value = 1500`, `result = Object4`,

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And what problem do you have with that attempt?

Comment: They are sorted? findIndex of the one that violates the "less than next one" criterion, subtract one.

Comment: Assuming that the array (of objects) will always be sorted, `const getResult = (haystack = objArray, needle = 400) => haystack.reduce((f, i) => (i.fee < needle ? {...i} : f || null) , null);`

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
let obs = [{fee: 150}, {fee: 300}, {fee: 450}, {fee: 700}];

function findObject(currentFee) {
// in case it is not garanteed that obs is sorted, doing this 
// would be necessary beforehand
   return obs.filter(o => o.fee > currentFee)[0]
};
```

Comment: prepend function to findObject ;-)

Comment: or, another way to write it may be: `const findObject = feeParam => obs.filter(o => o.fee > feeParam)[0];` ?

Comment: @MaikLowrey upps xD Edited

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```js
var objects = [{fee: 150}, {fee: 300}, {fee: 450}, {fee: 700}];

function find(input) {
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (objects[i + 1]) {
      if (objects[i].fee < input && input < objects[i + 1].fee) return objects[i].fee;    
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(find(701));
```

Comment: It is not working for value under 150

Comment: Have you tried with `find(701)`? The `for` loop goes till `objects.length` and within the loop it tries to access `objects[i+1]` - which means it will try to access index 4 if array-length is 4 and the parameter is above the 4th element's fee.

Comment: @jsN00b fixed it I think?

Comment: @ShadowLp174, by changing the outer `if` to `if (objects[i + 1])`, the code now returns `null` when parameter is `701`. The objective was, IIRC, to return `700` in this case. It does so because it tries to access `objects[4]` where `objects` array has only 4 elements (which are at indices: 0, 1, 2, 3). Please try `for` to terminate at `i < objects.length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I used filter with index. My answer is similar to the good answer by @RomanHDev. But my approach was to immediately use the index to decrement the match.

```js
const obs = [{fee: 150}, {fee: 300}, {fee: 450}, {fee: 700}];


findObject = feeParam => obs.filter((o, i) => {  
  if (o.fee >= feeParam) {    
    return obs[i] ?? null;
  }
})[0]

console.log( findObject('25',25) )
console.log( findObject('155',155) )
console.log( findObject('225',225) )
console.log( findObject('301',301) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but still an answer:

```
const array = [
  { fee: 150 },
  { fee: 300 },
  { fee: 450 },
  { fee: 700 },
 ]

function findClosest(input) {
    let diff = undefined
    let closest
    for(const element of array) {
       if(diff === undefined) diff = Math.abs(input - element.fee)
       if(diff >= Math.abs(input - element.fee)) {
         closest = element.fee
         diff = Math.abs(input - element.fee)
       }
       else continue
    } 
  
    return closest

} 

const closest = findClosest(290)
console.log(closest)
```